# uploading a saved trained model into MLKIT

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, firebase-mlkit

I have created a Multinominal naive bayes using sklearn and wrote it on jupiter model and saved it by joblib library as sav extension file. Now, I want to upload it into MLKit in order to use it in the future to connect to mobile application. However, while I uploading the file, There was an error that .sav is not a supported file type. Any idea what type of files exactly can be uploaded to ml kit to further be used in mobile app? or how can I save this model in a way that can be used to be uploaded in ML?

Answer (score 0):

When you upload it into MLKit, are you using the Firebase Console (https://console.firebase.google.com)?  ML Kit supports only Tensoflow Lite models.  Usually the model file's extension is ".tflite".

Comment: Thank you for youre response. Yes, I did use the console. Is there a way to convert any file into tflite?